# Is there any relationship between a Dirichlet series and the same series with the sequence "shifted" by one term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, big-list, dirichlet-series, analytic-combinatorics

Suppose
$$ F(s) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n^{s}} $$
is a Dirichlet series for the sequence $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots\in\mathbb{C}$. Then let
$$ G(s) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{(n+1)^{s}} $$
be the same series but with the sequence "shifted" by one index. Is there any known relationship between $F(s)$ and $G(s)$?

My question seems to be a subcase of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127580), but I think my question should stand on its own, because the levels of generality here are different enough to warrant possibly different answers.

I'm okay with multiple suggestions.

Comment: Think about it this way: $G(s) = \sum\frac{a_{n - 1}}{n^s}$. The most interesting cases of Dirichlet series are multiplicative functions $a_n$. What would you expect for $a_{n -1 }$ then? Basically chaos, I think.

Comment: Strangely, I think this is a really good question (especially given the analogy with power series) but where the answer is simply "nope".

Comment: $G(s)= \sum_{k\ge 0} {-s \choose k} F(s+k)$

Comment: @reuns This seems like a great suggestion. I see why it works, but I got stuck trying to prove it because it wasn't clear how to interchange summation signs in my proof. If you or anyone can prove this with a rigorous justification of interchanging of summations, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you think it is divergent. If $a_1\ne 0$ then need to restrict to $\Re(s) > 1$, otherwise it converges on the half plane where $F(s)$ converges. Restricting to $k$ large enough (depending on $s$) it converges absolutely.

Comment: @reuns I've made [another post regarding this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4462271).

Comment: Yes I was tired need $a_1=0$ in which case it converges without problem whenever $F(s)$ does

Answer (score 1):

There was an excellent suggestion made by user [reuns](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/reuns) that was later refined by [Sangchul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee).

> **Proposition.** Let $\sigma_a$ be the abscissa of absolute convergence of $F$. Then for each $s$ with $\Re(s) > \sigma$,
> $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-s}{k} [F(s+k) - a_1] = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(n+1)^s}, $$
> where the convergence of the series is absolute. Moreover,
> $$ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-s}{k} e^{-\varepsilon k} F(s+k) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(n+1)^s} $$
> (In other words, the proposed identity in OP holds in Abel summation sense.)

This is taken from [this post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4462322). For the sake of completeness, I will post their proof here as well.

> To prove the first claim, note that
>
> $$ \binom{-s}{k} = \frac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(s)} \frac{\Gamma(s+k)}{\Gamma(k+1)} \sim \frac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(s)} k^{s-1} \qquad \text{as } k \to \infty. $$
>
> So, there exists a constant $C = C(s) \in (0, \infty)$ such that $\left|\binom{-s}{k}\right|\leq C (k + 1)^{\Re(s)-1}$ for all $k \geq 0$. Then by this bound and the Tonelli's theorem together, we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left| \binom{-s}{k} \frac{a_n}{n^{s+k}} \right|
> &\leq C \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(k + 1)^{\Re(s)-1} |a_n|}{n^{\Re(s)+k}} \\
> &\leq C \biggl( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(k + 1)^{\Re(s)-1}}{2^k} \biggr)\biggl( \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{n^{\Re(s)}} \biggr)
> < \infty.
> \end{align*}
>
> So, by the Fubini's theorem,
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-s}{k} [F(s+k) - a_1]
> &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-s}{k} \frac{a_n}{n^{s+k}} \\
> &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s(1 + \frac{1}{n})^s}
> = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(n+1)^s}.
> \end{align*}
>
> The second claim then follows from the [Abel's theorem for power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) and
>
> $$ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-s}{k} e^{-\varepsilon k} a_1
> = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{a_1}{(1 + e^{-\varepsilon})^s}
> = \frac{a_1}{2^s}. $$